# How can I prepare slightly uneven tiled floor for vinyl 'planks'?

Tags: vinyl-flooring

I recently bought some very [nice vinyl planks](http://www.gerflor.com/int/floors-for-the-home/product-page/senso-rustic,135.html) for reflooring our kitchen.

It was only when I got home that I noticed it said they have to be installed on 'flat, smooth' surfaces. Our kitchen is currently tiled, and wavy in places.

I don't really want to go the route of self-leveling compound - for one thing I'm not entirely bothered about the floor being *level*, I just need it to be relatively *flat*.

What I need advice on is what kind of product can I use for filling in the fairly shallow 'dips' in the floor (i.e. about 1-2ft (50cm) wide and 3/16" (5mm) deep).

After that, I can just prime it and go... I hope

Comment: It's not usually a good idea to install one floor covering over another, rip up the tile and install the vinyl on the sub-floor.</obligatory comment>

Comment: I think vinyl plank flooring is a floating floor and is fine to put over any solid surface

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have used this product myself:
[DAP floor leveling compound](http://www.jamestowndistributors.com/userportal/product.do?part=164382&engine=adwords!6456&keyword=product_ad_55963&type=pla)

[image]

It is thick enough that it does not actually seek self-level, but it can be used with a good straight scrim to get to "TRUE" which means "flat not necessarily level/plum".

This should be perfect for you.  Follow up with a 1/8" layer of plywood if you like.

Comment: Guess I'm just cheap. but a 10 pound bag of leveling compound that you can mix with a little water right on the floor is only a couple of bucks. If you have a lot to do, the dry mix is much cheaper, but I admit premix is easy and convenient, but expensive.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try and find something like that (or the dry mix suggested by @shirlock) at the hardware store here.

Comment: Agreed, Shirlock, if you do this a lot, dry mix is the way to go.  But for a single room one time job, the pre mixed makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun, this is what the floor looked like half way through: in the background a finished 'flat' bit, in the foreground, freshly-laid (spilt?) 'self-leveling' compound.

[image]

And some anecdotal photos: cutting vinyl planks with a hooked blade *can* be risky...

[image]

[image]